# pwmWrite() dosen't run

Tags: pwm, servo, speech-recognition

```
    else if(strcmp(hyp,"MEDIUM") == 0)
    {
        system("espeak 'medium'");
        printf("%s\n", hyp);
        digitalWrite(LIGHT1, HIGH);
        pwmWrite (PWM_pin1, 524) ;
```

}

i try to control servo using voice but the program doen't run, can someone help me ?
note : PWM_pin1 = 1

Comment: Why do you think we know how pwmWrite has been configured.  It's always best to post a complete executable example to support a question.  This snippet does not help us diagnose the problem.